# How to handle `ConcurrencyViolation` using axios in react vite?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting `429 (Too Many Requests)` but when I trace this error in my console Network Tab and got `error_code : "ConcurrencyViolation"` with `message : "Max concurrency allowed 1 per 1 seconds"`

I know how to use ajax in react but not sure why I'm getting this error.

And researched for react-xhr packages even something different but tried to install it including p-limit, xhr, cross-fetch... etc. but nothing works.

Error screen shots:

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDDWr.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Soo.png)

here is what I did so far:

- *useFetch.js* (data fetching hook)

```
useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (ref.current) {
            const sleep = (s) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000)); //how to reimplement this because I guess here is something I'm doing wrong!
            (async () => {
                try {
                    await sleep(10);
                    const res = await axios.request(url, options);
                    setNews(res.data.articles);
                } catch (err) {
                    if (err.response) {
                        setError(err.response.data);
                    } else if (err.request) {
                        console.log(err.request);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
                    }
                } finally {
                    await sleep(30);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })();
        }

        return () => {
            ref.current = false;
        };
    }, [url, ref]);
```

How to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: PLEASE someone help me!   There is just only one thing I'm able to do it i.e DEBUG THE SITE by enabling `Any xhr breakpoint`. that's not good but I can't do this in anyway for the performance optimization of react app. If anyone knows please suggest something!!